# Finding the area of an open rectangular tank

Tags: geometry, area, rectangles

I tried approaching this as a normal rectangle, but my answer doesn't seem to be in the options. Here's the question -

> An open rectangular tank: 4m long, 3m wide and 4m high is made out of a thin metal sheet. Find the area of the metal sheet used in its construction.

Comment: you have to sum up the area of 5 rectangles.

Comment: @d_e $6$ or $5$?  It does say open after all, which I'm assuming means it has no top.

Comment: thanks Mike you right. I'll edit my comment.

Comment: Pls could you explain?

Comment: think of Cuboid/Box without the top. it has 5 sides. each side it rectangle. can you see it ?

Comment: @d_e wow, perfect illustration...i get now. But area equals width * height = '(3 * 4) * 5 = 60'. Which i still got wrong

Comment: look @Harish answer below.

Comment: @Nookjay How big is the bottom? $4\times3$, right? What about the walls? Are all of the walls the same size as each other? I recommend drawing a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sine, the tank is open say at the top then surface area of the tank
$$=(\text{total surface area of lateral walls of the tank  })+\text{(area of rectangular base of the tank})$$

$$=2(\text{(length)}\times(\text{height})+\text{(width)}\times(\text{height}))+\text{(length)}\times(\text{width} )$$

Area of total surface of the tank $$=2(4\times 4+3\times 4)+3\times 4=2(28)+12=68 \ m^2$$